# problems with my touchpad on my netbook

Tags: laptop, touchpad

ive been having trouble with my touchpad its a synaptic pad. my problem is whenever i drag my finger across i a lot of times get this grey circle and i cant move anymore i have to take my finger off and start again its very annoying and the icon for the touchpad thats by the clock gets like a curved arrow in it and if i move my finger a little bit while this grey circle appears the arrow rotates in a circle its very weird! i have a Asus 1101HAB netbook and ive tried to update the driver when the asus updates appear and when i do it and restart the computer, then a couple days later maybe it pops up again saying i have an update and its for the touchpad and its the same version... not sure if its a bigger problem its only a week old that ive had this computer. If someone could help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok it looks like my initial assumption was correct. After a bit of research on the Asus website, I found that your laptop should have multi-touch. This allows you to do two finger scrolling etc.

Im thinking by your discription of the taskbar icon that it thinks you are doing a rotate motion on the touchpad, hence the rotating arrow. This kind of action doesnt normally cancel until you remove your finger from the touchpad, as you mentioned.

If this is correct, then I would suggest turning the multi-touch settings off if you dont use them. If you do then you should be able to adjust the sensetivity of the touchpad, to make it less sensative as maybe you are accidentally touching it with other fingers and triggering the rotate function.

Could you perhaps turn off the multi-touch settings for a few days and see if this solves the problem?

Comment: There's a circular scrolling option as well, where all you have to do is look like you're doing circles a lot on the pad and that initiates a scrolling-type behavior too.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue, hence coming across your question. Could it be the scroll function that is sliding up and down the right hand side of the touchpad scrolls up and down and sliding along the bottom of the touchpad scrolls left and right. Very useful if you know it exists but confusing when it happens randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the touchpad software that came with your laptop and make sure everything is configured correctly.

It sounds like your computer could be mixing up the movement of the mouse with keyboard strokes. Which I would usually say is a driver problem, however as you've updated your drivers this is the only other solution.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle with Synaptics configuration and its settings, I gave up on it and uninstalled that software. After this using the mouse pad and the little button stick has become very simple and efficient on my HP laptop.